# Create .NET Framework project command line from an existing template

Tags: .net, command-line

I have exported a `Project Template` for `.NET Framework Web Application` using visual studio export tool which resulted a `.zip` file in `Visual Studio 2019\My Exported Templates`

I couldn't seem to find a client other that `dotnet` for `.NET core`.

Is there any `cmd` tool for `.NET Framework` that achieves that? any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. Windows doesn't even have any built-in command-line programs for manipulating PKZIP (`*.zip`) files - despite Explorer supporting them since 1998.

Comment: What I could suggest is writing your own Batch file that uses `7z.exe` to extract a template zip file to a named directory.